# Select all email addresses beginning with 5 numeric characters (regular expression)

Tags: mysql, regex

I am trying to select all email address in my database that begin with 5 numeric characters but am having real issues with the syntax. I think it's simple but have spent the last two hours trying to get it working and it just failing!

I have tried:

```
SELECT * FROM `phplist_user_user` WHERE email REGEXP ^\d{5}
```

Hope someone can assist with what I believe is quite a simple query.

Comment: `REGEXP '[0-9]{5}.*'`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

MySQL regex engine (POSIX) doesn't support `\d` for digits. Use `[0-9]`

You can use this query:

```
SELECT * FROM `phplist_user_user` WHERE email REGEXP "^[0-9]{5}";
```

Comment: I need to refine slightly in that the 6th character should be "@".

Comment: SELECT *
FROM `phplist_user_user`
WHERE email REGEXP "^[0-9]{5}[@]"